# I have two data signals with respect to time how can I plot them against each other and eliminate time if the data points are not equal?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, matlab, excel

I have two signals each have been plotted against time is there any way to eliminate the time  and plot the signal1 vs signal2. The problem I am facing is the number of data points is not equal signal 1 has 1766 data points while the signal 2 has 845 but they are bound within almost identical time limits for signal 1 the bounds are 0-76 seconds for signal 2 they are between 0-84 seconds. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe first interpolate the signals to the same time grid?